# Print Receipt in android

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, android-wifi, network-printers

I have to print some receipt using my own android application. Is it possible in android.New In android.Nothing Helpful found.Does I have to use third party API's? Question I am asking just because there is no proper solution,or documentation for print.If there is some documentation or any solution .please provide me link.I need to know about the possibilities of printing document and receipt in android.All I have got while searching is that "I have to use third party app or tools for that." Got some code to print text via Bluetooth Printer.

Comment: Do u need to integrate Bluetooth Printer ?

Comment: yes I have to for printing some Receipt.

Comment: You have many options for this, but Zebra Printer seems best to me. Their API are decently documented, and you will get demo source code along with their SDK. One of their printer is http://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/mobile/qln420.html